# Can't insert data to sql database from android application

Tags: php, sql

This is my php code for insert account into the table

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];

$mysql_qry = "insert into account_data (username,password) values ('$user_name','$user_pass')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
if($result) {
echo "insert success";
}
else {
echo "Failed insert of '$user_name', '$user_pass' ";
}


?>
```

And this is the php for login

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from account_data where username like '$user_name' and password like '$user_pass';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "Accesso riuscito";
}
else {
echo "Accesso non riuscito: username ($user_name) o password ($user_pass) non corretti ";
}


?>
```

I can't understand why the second code works perfectly and the second one doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: I can't understand why the second code works perfectly and the second one doesn't work? why second is used on both place?

Comment: Sorry, I ment the login code works while the insert code dosen't

Comment: Are you sure you are using right script in action tag? Because I dont see any problem with yr code

Comment: First thing make sure your both php file is in the same directory since you are requiring conn.php and second code is working so make sure this file is included which is important and second thing the method is POST for calling second api.

Comment: Now do one thing more instead of using your parameter from POST method 
you initialize it with some value like  :
$user_name = "Andrea"
$user_pass="abc"
and now copy the url and hit it on your browser and check it if it echos insert success.

Comment: The file are in the same directory, I don't think the problem is in the connection because the "conn.php" echos "connection success" from both code. I tried also to initialize my parameter but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: you tried your own parameter and hit your url on browser what it shows then?

Comment: " (Connessione riuscita) Failed insert of 'andrea', '12345' " .I've also checked the database and nothing has been inserted. The part in the brackets is from conn.php

Comment: @AndreaGennaro i am wondering how come your second code is working when your first code is failing to insert in the first place because there is nothing in account_data unless you don't run your insert query or you would have manually in your database.

Comment: Yes, I've manually inserted data in the first row of the databse. The problem must be in the "$mysql_qry" because connection works, and the "$_POST" methods work as well.

Comment: And the java code that I use for sending data is the same, the only difference is in the URL http://...../login.php for the login and http://...../insert.php for insert data

Comment: @AndreaGennaro Do one last thing and tell me what happened : instead od taking $result just put your condition directly in "if" condition like "if(mysqli_mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry))" if still it fails try to echo only $conn and check whether the database is connected or not. And last thing your query is PERFECT it worked for me.

Comment: Tried both. Database is connected but insert data still fails. Anyway if my query worked for you I don't know what else I should check to find the problem.

Comment: You can use mysql_error for check mysql errors.

Comment: Could you explain me how to use it, please? I'm not a very expert of sql